# how to download multiple images for my website?

Tags: python, string, list, urllib

So i was trying this for a single image.

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("link.com","name1.jpg")
```

and found out that the link of the images is constant and only one digit is variable.

The first link : https://image.slidesharecdn.com/marketinginternationalsept2013-150330215818-conversion-gate01/95/marketing-international-1-638.jpg?cb=1427770871

The last link : https://image.slidesharecdn.com/marketinginternationalsept2013-150330215818-conversion-gate01/95/marketing-international-92-638.jpg?cb=1427770871

> > > Where only 1 to 92 number is variable.

I'm stuck in making a list incremented through that number in the link, and a list for the image name.To automate this process instead of downloading one by one like i did.
Any help please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution Didn't work for several problems.
So i went for this solution:

```
for i in list(range(1,92)): 
    link_1 = "image.slidesharecdn.com/…" name = str(i)+".jpg" 
    print(link_1, name) 
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link_1, name)
```

And it worked! thanks for help –

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the image numbers and get each one individually.

```
import urllib.request

for i in range(92):
    import urllib
    f = open(f'{i+1}.jpg','wb')
    f.write(urllib.request.urlopen(f'https://image.slidesharecdn.com/marketinginternationalsept2013-150330215818-conversion-gate01/95/marketing-international-1{i+1}-638.jpg').read())
    f.close()
```

Comment: your solution Didn't work for several problems.

Comment: So i went for this solution: 

for i in list(range(1,92)):
    link_1 = "https://image.slidesharecdn.com/marketinginternationalsept2013-150330215818-conversion-gate01/95/marketing-international-"+str(i)+"-638.jpg?cb=1427770871"
    name = str(i)+".jpg"
    print(link_1, name)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link_1, name)

And it worked! thanks for help

Comment: Yeah they basically do the same thing. One thing to mention, do not convert the range to a list. It is completely redundant and will make the code more inefficient. Just use `for i in range(92):`